# Laravel queue email property values are lost in handle() function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 7 and recently I decided to implement Laravel Mail Queue. My project send around 40 different emails and sometimes waiting for the email to be sent in order to proceed to the next step is just wrong.

I never create independent classes for each email template, instead I like to write code in a way that saves me time, so I always do the following:

```
Mail::send('mails/contact-form', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($data)
{
    $message->to($data->to['email'], $data->to['name'])->subject($data->subject);
});
```

Quite simple. Now, converting this into a Queueable Email, made me creating a job called `SendEmailJob` which I intend to be the only class used to send all the 40 emails.

```
class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;
    protected $file;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data, $file)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::send($this->file, ['data' => $this->data], function($message)
        {
            $message->to($this->data->to['email'], $this->data->to['name'])->subject($this->data->subject);
        });
    }
}
```

And what happens is that all the content of `$this->data` is empty except the model information.

`$this->data->to` and `$this->data->subject` are all null, but if I log the content in the `__construct()` they exist!

```
public function __construct($data, $file)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->file = $file;
    
    Log::debug(json_encode($this->data->to)); // Has value
}

public function handle()
{
    Log::debug(json_encode($this->data->to)); // Suddenly it does not have value 
}
```

My `$data` variable usually contains the following:

```
$data = \App\Models\SomeModel::something();
$data->to = ['name' => '', 'email' => ''];
$data->subject = 'Some subject';
```

What does Laravel do behind scenes that makes some of the properties values to be lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I'm still not sure why Laravel loses the properties values, but:

```
$data = new \stdClass;
$data->the_model_data = \App\Models\SomeModel::something();
$data->to = ...;
$data->subject = ...;
```

This way the properties are not lost.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the SerializesModels trait, which instructs the job when it is pushed onto the queue to only store the ID of the model and how to retrieve it from the database. Any custom properties that you assign to the model will be lost, because upon unserializing it'll fetch the corresponding record from the database and repopulate the model with that information.

The reason Laravel does this is because models can become very complex (with relations etc) and would create a very taxing payload to store when queued.

To avoid losing the information, it would be better to declare separate properties for your `to` and `subject` data, as they would be serialized in the payload separately.

```
class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;
    protected $to
    protected $subject
    protected $file;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data, $file)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->to = $data->to;
        $this->subject = $data->subject;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::send($this->file, ['data' => $this->data], function($message)
        {
            $message->to($this->to['email'], $this->to['name'])->subject($this->subject);
        });
    }
}
```